# Where should the code go; in Fragment or in Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Imagine this situation:

- Activity.
- Activity contains layout with 2 fragments. FragmentA and FragmentB
- FragmentA has a layout with a button that should print a toast "Hello".
- FragmentB has a layout with a button that should print a toast "Bye".
- Both buttons have a onClick attribute set. First one with "sayHello" and second one with "SayBye".

So which is the correct way of finally displaying the toast?

Case A:

```
public class ActivityCustom extends FragmentActivity{
    [...]
    public void sayHello(View v){
        //SHOW TOAST HERE
    }
    public void sayBye(View v){
        //SHOW TOAST HERE
    }

}
```

Case B:

```
public class ActivityCustom extends FragmentActivity{
    [...]
    public void sayHello(View v){
        ((FragmentA)this.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA)).showToast();
    }
    public void sayBye(View v){
        ((FragmentB)this.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentB)).showToast();
    }

}
```

I'm a bit confused about that.

Because if we delegate all the work on the fragments, I guess Activity will be kinda clear of code. It will just have the code to "connect" the two fragments, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a matter of OOP principles specifically "encapsulation", i don't think activity should contain code that do not care about, hence the proper way taking on count your example would be having each toast message in the Fragment because is their behavior and in case of modifications you actually know where to go, unlike having everything in the activity becoming the single point for every single functionality losing maintainability and extensibility, since there will be a point where all your code will rely on your activity. By the way there's nothing wrong on having Activities with just a few code, is actually good to keep code out of activity if it doesn't have to do with the activity life cycle itself...

Regards!

Comment: Think about it this way: What if you want to use that fragment again in another Activity? If the code is in the Activity, then it needs to be copied into the new Activity also. If it's in the fragment, it just works.

Comment: So as a matter of reusability, the best idea is to keep the working code in fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should show the toasts in each fragment. In FragmentA's onCreateView method, you get the button, add the listener and show the toast in the onCLick() method there. Same on FragmentB.

No problem for the activity to have less code.

Comment: Both ways are easy to implement, but, is there any recommendation about doing that in any particular way?

Comment: Fragments are meant to be modular. Imagine if you will use FragmentA in another activity, it should do the job with no modifications in the containing activity.